# sinatra in rubymine 3.24 wont start webrick

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rubymine

I wonder why this Sinatra hello World doesnt start webrick from within 
my Rubymine 3.2.4

```
require 'sinatra'
# set :bind, '0.0.0.0'
get '/' do
  "Hello" 
end
```

Output in the Run window from Rubymine:

```
C:\Ruby193\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:/Users/gonzo/RubymineProjects/jktest/sinatra.rb

Process finished with exit code 0
```

on the other hand, started this script on the commandline
does the expected...

```
gonzo@uhura ~/prj/sinatra
$ /cygdrive/c/Ruby193/bin/ruby test.rb
[2015-04-04 07:50:11] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-04-04 07:50:11] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2014-11-13) [i386-mingw32]
== Sinatra (v1.4.6) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from WEBrick
[2015-04-04 07:50:11] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=11212 port=4567
```

Rubymine uses same SDK , ruby 1.9.3

any Idea, anybody?

Comment: It's been a while since I ran Ruby on Windows, but are those 2 different Ruby installations? One's running via Cygwin and the other from `C:\Ruby193`. Also, don't use Webrick for anything, just use any other server and your problems will more than likely disappear (in this regard, anyway:)

Comment: No, no different installations, /cygwin/c equals c:\

Comment: No, no different installations, /cygwin/c equals c:\. Same behaviour on a Linux System too, with Rubymine 3.2.4. Webrick is started from Sinatra by default, ok, i can try to configure sinatra t use another webserver. But i think it has someting to do with Rubymine, i can try next week a new Rubynine Testversion, its 7.0 now, BUT i actually dont need all tthe featuers, for my little scripting, Rubymine 3.2.4 is ok i think, also new Version will cost some Bucks :-(

Comment: Have a look at http://bundler.io/ and in the Gemfile if you specify a different server, (e.g. Puma or Thin) then Sinatra should use that instead without further configuration. I'd suggest installing via `bundle install --binstubs --path=vendor` (see http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundle_install.html) to sandbox the gems for the project and then running via `bundle exec ruby app.rb` (always prefix the `bundle exec part` to use the project's gems and not your general installation's)

Answer (score 1):

If i use this Code, webrick starts from within my Rubymine 3.2.4.

```html
# my_app.rb
require 'sinatra/base'

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  # ... app code here ...

  get '/' do
  "Hello"
  end
  # start the server if ruby file executed directly
  run! if app_file == $0
end
```

If commented the line #run! if app_file == $0
it wont start and sme behaviour as above.

Now i can go on and learn some more sinatra :-)

Comment: the `run! if app_file == $0` is needed because you're using [modular style](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Modular%20vs.%20Classic%20Style) (by putting it in a class and inheriting from `Sinatra::Base`), otherwise you'd probably using a config.ru (rackup) file to start the app. As to why modular style fixes your problem and classic doesn't, I don't know the answer to that…